# React Navigation - Can't get the header updated

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-navigation

I have the following code on my react native application but cannot get the screen header updated when I am navigating to the Dashboard Screen after login. This is so simple but since I don't get what is wrong here I am posting this.

After login call I navigate to the Dashboard.

```
this.props.navigation.navigate('Dashboard', {
     title: 'Dashboard'
})
```

My DashboardScreen.js is as follows.

This is exactly like in the documentation from react navigation library.

```
class DashboardScreen extends React.Component {
    static navigationOptions = ({navigation}) => {
        const {params} = navigation.state;

        let title = navigation.state.params.title ? navigation.state.params.title : 'This is Sparta!';

        return {
            title: title
        };
    };

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <ScrollView>
                <Card>
                    <Text>Dashboard Screen</Text>
                </Card>
            </ScrollView>
        )
    }
}
```

My base StackNavigator.

```
const StackNavigator = createStackNavigator({
    Login: {
        screen: LoginScreen
    },
    Dashboard: {
        screen: DashboardScreen
    }
}, {
    initialRouteName: "Login",
});

class App extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <StackNavigator/>
        )
    }
}

export default App;
```

I'm new to react native so react navigation is also new to me. Tried out various methods including passing additional props with navigationOptions.

Can someone point out the exact problem? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you please share your navigation code from login?

Comment: It is there in the question. I navigate like this code below

`this.props.navigation.navigate('Dashboard', {
     title: 'Dashboard'
})`
It navigates but doesn't update the header.

Answer (score 0):

```
class DashboardScreen extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            title: this.props.navigation.state.params.title
        };
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <ScrollView>
                <Card>
                    <Text>{this.state.title}</Text>
                </Card>
            </ScrollView>
        )
    }
}
```

I hope this will help you.

Comment: Thanks but, 
Why is it used in the render() ?? How will this update the header?

Comment: I just used for example.You can use wherever you want.